# Overwriting SystemVersion.plist (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, authorization, overwrite

I'm writing an application that can change your Mac OS X version for a short period (few seconds) to launch an application that is to old or to new for your Version.

It reads the version from SystemVersion.plist (/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist) then sets the new required version.
Save (overwrite) the file and launch the app and then change the version back
to the orginal version.

This is the first part of the code (reads version and tries to overwrite)

```
// Get SystemVersion.plist as Dictionary 
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/CoreServices"];
NSString *SystemVersionString = [bundle pathForResource:@"SystemVersion" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *SystemVersionDir = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:SystemVersionString];

// Get current version (Systemversion, ProductUserVisibleVersion)
NSString *SystemVersion = [SystemVersionDir objectForKey:@"ProductVersion"];

// Get desired version from text field
NSString *DesiredVersion = [_Text_version stringValue];

[_Text_Info setStringValue:SystemVersion];

// Set new version
[SystemVersionDir setObject:DesiredVersion forKey:@"ProductVersion"];

// Write (save) plist
if([SystemVersionDir writeToFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist" atomically:YES])
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

The problem is with the `'writeToFile'`. If I write to my desktop or something everything goes fine and it creates a new file. Also if I copy the file to my desktop and overwrite it there it goes fine. But it needs to overwrite the one in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`.

I guess I need authorization or something. However I've looked into that but it seems an awful lot of work and my mind is mess because of that.

Isn't there a simpler way to do this, perhaps a class that helps?

Note: Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Developer Preview 3 (Xcode 4.3.1)

Comment: You need ROOT access, google how to achieve that. **It's not good to change the System Version though**, just so you know.

Comment: Why don't you change the system version constraints in the application, instead?

Comment: I understand I need to have root access, however it involves creating a whole helper application, isn't there a simple code consinsting out of a few lines? And I know it's not good to change the System Version.. I'm aware of this risks.

Comment: @LaC, Because that doesn't always work ;)